# Fastest way to Compare the [1:] elements of a value in 2 dict of lists

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, comparison

I have the following two massive dictionaries:

```
Dic1={0:['F','15','O+','5'],1:['M','12','O+'],2:[F,'20','O-'],3:['F','10','A+'],4:['M','45','?']...}

Dic2={0:['M','15','O+','5'],1:['M','12','O+'],2:[F,'20','A-'],3:['F','10','A+'],4:['F','15','?'],5:['M','10','A+']...}
```

and I need to compare both  to find the  V[1:]'s that are equal in both dictionaries  to combine them in just one dictionary and delete the value from the other one.

New Dic1:

```
Dic1={0:['F,M','15','O+','5'],1:['2M','12','O+'],2:[F,'20','O-'],3:['2F,M','10','A+'],4:['M','45','?']...}
```

New Dic2:

```
Dic2={2:[F,'20','A-'],4:['F','15','?'],...}
```

The idea I have so far is:

```
for ((key1, value1), (key2, value2)) in zip(Dic1.items(),  Dic2.items()):
 if value1[1:]==value2[1:]:
     value1.append(value2[:1])     
     del Dic1[Value2]
```

But I have problems with it and since the dictionaries are very large I need a  time-efficient way, I thought about set but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Why is this a zero-indexed `dict()` instead of a simple list of lists? I don't see much difference...

Comment: The reason is that the dictionaries were made from a more complex database and it looks like the iteration in a dictionary is faster.

Answer (score 0):

The following should generate the desired results:

```
Dic1={0:['F','15','O+','5'],1:['M','12','O+'],2:['F','20','O-'],3:['F','10','A+'],4:['M','45','?']}
Dic2={0:['M','15','O+','5'],1:['M','12','O+'],2:['F','20','A-'],3:['F','10','A+'],4:['F','15','?'],5:['M','10','A+']}

for i in Dic1.keys():
    if Dic1[i][1:] == Dic2[i][1:]:
        if Dic1[i][0] == Dic2[i][0]:
            Dic1[i][0] = '2' + Dic1[i][0]
        else:
            Dic1[i][0] += ',' + Dic2[i][0]
        Dic2.pop(i) 

print Dic1
print Dic2
```

The above produces:

{0: ['F,M', '15', 'O+', '5'], 1: ['2M', '12', 'O+'], 2: ['F', '20', 'O-'], 3: ['2F', '10', 'A+'], 4: ['M', '45', '?']}

{2: ['F', '20', 'A-'], 4: ['F', '15', '?'], 5: ['M', '10', 'A+']}

Comment: Iterating a dictionary goes through its keys.  Therefore, you can use `for i in Dic1:` instead of `for i in Dic1.keys():`.

Comment: This works but does not iterate in all the keys for example is the dictionaries instead are: 

Dic1={0:['F','15','O+','5'],1:['M','12','O+'],2:['F','20','O-'],3:['F','10','A+'],4:['M','45','?']}

Dic2={0:['M','15','O+','5'],1:['M','12','O+'],2:['F','20','A-'],3:['F','10','A+'],4:['F','15','?'],6:['F','15','O+','5']}

The last value on dic2 is not taking in consideration and I get :

{0: ['F,M', '15', 'O+', '5'], 1: ['2M', '12', 'O+'], 2: ['F', '20', 'O-'], 3: ['2F', '10', 'A+'], 4: ['M', '45', '?']}
{2: ['F', '20', 'A-'], 4: ['F', '15', '?'], 6: ['F', '15', 'O+', '5']}